# Disable jquery function when writing in a text box using if/else statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

Yo!

I have the following function implemented on my site, which allows the user to press up/down to fluidly scroll through different sections of the page:

```
// CONTROL TOP NAVBAR WITH UP/DOWN ON KEYBOARD
        $(document).keydown(function(e) {
          var p = $("li.active");
          if (e.keyCode === 38) {
          e.preventDefault();
          p.prev().find("a").click();
          } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
          e.preventDefault();
          p.next().find('a').click();
          }
        });
```

This works fine. However, I also have a contact form on the page. When the user is typing in the contact form, I'd like them to be able to move up/down with their keyboard in the textbox to navigate properly. However, it currently still controls the navbar.

My contact form has the id of #contactform. Code is here:

```
<form name="contactform" id="contactform" method="post" action="/contact/" _lpchecked="1">
    <ul class="form-block">

      <!-- HONEYPOT -->
      <li class="on-no-robots" style="height:0px; text-indent:-9999px; font-size:0px; overflow:hidden;">
        <label>Humans Don't Submit This!! If you can see this, you don't have CSS, and you scare me. This is just here to filter out automated comments!</label>
        <input name="robotest" id="robotest" type="text" />
      </li>
      <!-- HONEYPOT -->

      <li class="third">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" class="required" />
      </li>
      <li class="third">
        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" class="required email" />
      </li>
      <li class="third">
        <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="" />
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h3>How can we help you?</h3>
    <ul class="form-block">
      <li class="full">
        <textarea name="comments" id="comments" class="required"></textarea>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Talk to us" />
      </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Is it possible to make a conditional statement that says "if #contactform#name, #contactform#email, #contactform#comments is in focus, disable this function"?

I'm fairly bad at jquery, but here was my attempt:

```
        $(document).keydown(function(e) {
            if ($("#contactform input", "#contactform textarea").is(":focus")){
                return;
            }

            else{
              var p = $("li.active");
              if (e.keyCode === 38) {
              e.preventDefault();
              p.prev().find("a").click();
              } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
              e.preventDefault();
              p.next().find('a').click();
              }
            }       
        });
```

Currently, the up/down arrow function works fine, although the conditional statment is wrong. What have I missed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a JavaScript routine (in use on [this site](http://www.mynextmove.org/explore/ip)) to detect whether a user is in a text field:

```
function inTextField(event)
{
  var elem = event.target || event.srcElement;
  if (elem.nodeType == 3)
    elem = elem.parentNode;

  return (elem.tagName == "TEXTAREA" ||
          (elem.tagName == "INPUT" && (elem.getAttribute("type") == "text")));
}
```

It could be improved by using jQuery syntax, but even as-is it should be enough to get your conditional working:

```
if (inTextField(e)){
    return;
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following ?

```
if($("#contactform input").is(':focus') || $("#contactform textarea").is(':focus')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/F9AY3/)

Comment: It worked in one sense - pressing up/down when in the textbox now keeps the page stable. However, this code prevents you from actually entering any text, which kinda defeats the purpose!

Answer (score 0):

Here I have done complete solution for above issue, you check demo link here.

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp9f

Note: if you check output on codebins, once load page then first click on anywhere on output area so that script will be detect document key down event.

**HTML**:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#">
      Menu1
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Menu1
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Menu2
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Menu3
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      Menu4
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<form name="contactform" id="contactform" method="post" action="#" _lpchecked="1">
  <ul class="form-block">
    <!-- HONEYPOT -->
    <li class="on-no-robots" style="height:0px; text-indent:-9999px; font-size:0px; overflow:hidden;">
      <label>
        Humans Don't Submit This!! If you can see this, you don't have CSS, and you scare me. This is just here to filter out automated comments!
      </label>
      <input name="robotest" id="robotest" type="text"/>
    </li>
    <!-- HONEYPOT -->
    <li class="third">
      <label for="name">
        Name
      </label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" class="required" />
    </li>
    <li class="third">
      <label for="email">
        Email Address
      </label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="required email" />
    </li>
    <li class="third">
      <label for="phone">
        Phone Number
      </label>
      <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="" />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h3>
    How can we help you?
  </h3>
  <ul class="form-block">
    <li class="full">
      <textarea name="comments" id="comments" class="required">
      </textarea>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Talk to us" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menu{
  list-style:none;
  padding:1px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.menu li{
  background:#112288;
  padding:5px;
}
.menu li:hover,.menu li.active{
  background:#1144cd;
}
.menu li a{
  color:#eee;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.menu li a:hover{
  text-decoration:underline;
}
#contactform{
  border:1px solid #223388;
  width:50%;
  background:#5888a9;
  margin-left:5px;
  display:inline-block;
}
#contactform ul{
  padding:5px;
}
#contactform h3{
  margin-left:10px;
}
#contactform li{
  list-style:none;
  margin-left:10px;
}

#contactform input[type=text],#contactform textarea{
  border:1px solid #223388;
}
#contactform input[type=text]:focus,#contactform textarea:focus{
  background:#d4c8fb;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $(".menu li.active").click();
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (typeof(e.target.name) != "undefined" && e.target.name != "" &&   $(e.target).parents("#contactform").length > 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            var p = $(".menu li.active");
            if (e.keyCode === 38) {
                e.preventDefault();
                p.prev().find("a").click();
            } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
                e.preventDefault();
                p.next().find('a').click();
            }
        }
    });

    $(".menu li").click(function() {
        $(".menu li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp9f